# SQL Query to insert into a particular column from output of select query

Tags: mysql

I have a query as shown below:

```
select department as departmentname,count(distinct(uid)) as userscnt 
from outlier_report where department is not null group by department ;
```

I want to insert this into outlier_output table which is already populated and  has about 20 fields including departmentname and user_count (this field is empty). 
I want to put the userscnt field from the output of the select into the outlier_output table where the department=outlier_report.departmentment_name

I am assuming it would be something like this:

```
Insert into outlier_output(user_count Select department, count(distinct(uid) as userscnt from outlier_report where the department=outlier_report.departmentment_name)
```

How would the exact query be?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you expecting the row with that department name to exist in the output table already?

Comment: yes I am expecting that department name to exist already.

Answer (score 0):

Standard insert-select format is:

```
INSERT INTO `tableA` ([field_list])
SELECT [results corresponding to items in the field list in the same order as the field list]
[etc...]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how the query syntax works:

```
insert into outlier_output(departmentname, usercount) 
    select department as departmentname,count(distinct(uid)) as userscnt 
    from outlier_report 
    where department is not null group by department ;
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the aliasing is not required, but highly recommended for clarity (in my opinion at least).

Comment: its a "insert into select *" query. There are no sub-queries, where do you want to add alias here?

Comment: I was not saying to add alias; I was just pointing out that the field aliases you have are a good practice Although personally, I would've aliased the count field `usercount` to match exactly with the field it is being inserted into, rather than `userscnt`; but that is just my own pedantry.

Comment: Well, I wrote the query as per the details mentioned in the "question" to make sure the person who asked the question understands how the mapping of select and insert columns match. Hence kept the column names same as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

I see `Particular column` and `where the department = outlier_report.department_name`.
So I think, You want to UPDATE instead of INSERT.

Please try this :

```
update outlier_output a
inner join (
    select department as departmentname,
    count(distinct(uid)) as userscnt 
    from outlier_report 
    where department is not null 
    group by department 
) b on a.department = b.departmentname
set a.user_count = b.userscnt
```

And this is for INSERT

```
insert into outlier_output  (department,user_count)
select department as departmentname,
count(distinct(uid)) as userscnt 
from outlier_report 
where department is not null 
group by department
```

Comment: for the insert it is not matching the department in the outlier_report and outlier_output

Comment: @pri_dev Yes, because INSERT means, you add new row in outlier_output. so you need the UPDATE statement. Try the first query instead of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need INSERT as you have already populated them.  You just need to update the user_count column in your table.

```
UPDATE outlier_output a set 
    a.user_count=(select count(distinct(b.uid)) 
                         from outlier_report b 
                  where b.department=a.departmentname );
```

Comment: this sounds promising, let me try this

Comment: This query is taking really long time! I guess there needs to be a way to make it fast?

Comment: I guess you have a lot of entries in your table outlier_report.  You may consider adding an index on your column  "department".